# NullPointerException when totalPriceEditText is referred

Tags: java, android

I am new to Java and Android and I want to make an Android program that lets the users to type in the tag price and the program is able to show the final price. (after the tax which is 8%) I am required to use Netbean. There are no red lines nor error messages. But every time I ran it, it ended up with "Unfortunately, Tax Price Calculator has to stop" showed in the emulator. Please help me. I do appreciate everyone's answer. Thanks!!!!!!

TaxCalculator.java:

```
package com.finalproject.taxcalculator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.text.Editable;

public class TaxCalculator extends Activity{

private static final String TAG_PRICE = "TAG_PRICE";
private static final String TOTAL_PRICE = "TOTAL_PRICE";
private static final double TAX_RATE = 0.08;//Tax rate in Philadelphia

private double tagPrice;//Tag price entered by the user
private double totalPrice;//Total prices calculated by the program

private EditText tagPriceEditText;//accepts input for tag prices
private EditText totalPriceEditText;//displays total prices after tax


/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // constants used when saving/restoring state
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);// call superclass's version
    setContentView(R.layout.main);// inflate the GUI

    // check if app just started or is being restored from memory
    if ( savedInstanceState == null ) // the app just started running
       {
            tagPrice = 0.0; // initialize the tag price to zero

       } // end if
    else // app is being restored from memory, not executed from scratch
       {
         // initialize the tag price to saved amount
            tagPrice = savedInstanceState.getDouble(TAG_PRICE); 

       } // end else

         // get references to tag and total price edit text
            tagPriceEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tagPriceEditText);
            tagPriceEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.totalPriceEditText);

         // tagPriceEditTextWatcher handles tagPriceEditText's onTextChanged event
            tagPriceEditText.addTextChangedListener(tagPriceEditTextWatcher);
}// end method onCreate


private void updateStandard() 
{
    // calculate the total price after the tax
    totalPrice = tagPrice * (1 + TAX_RATE);
    // set totalPriceEditText's text to total price
    totalPriceEditText.setText(String.format("%.02f", totalPrice));
} // end method updateStandard

// save values of tagPriceEditText 
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
   super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

   outState.putDouble(TAG_PRICE, tagPrice);


} // end method onSaveInstanceState

// event-handling object that responds to tagPriceEditText's events    
private TextWatcher tagPriceEditTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() 
{
  // called when the user enters a number
  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
     int before, int count) 
  {         
     // convert billEditText's text to a double
     try
     {
        tagPrice = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
     } // end try
     catch (NumberFormatException e)
     {
        tagPrice = 0.0; // default if an exception occurs
     } // end catch 

     // update the tagPriceEditText
     updateStandard();
  } // end method onTextChanged

  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
  {
  } // end method afterTextChanged

  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
     int after) 
  {
  } // end method beforeTextChanged

}; // end tagPriceEditTextWatcher

} // end class TaxCaculator
```

from main.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" 
 android:background="#FFF" android:id="@+id/tableLayout" 
 android:stretchColumns="1,2,3" android:padding="5dp">


  <!-- tagPriceInputRow -->
       <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/tagPriceInputRow">

     <EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
           android:id="@+id/tagPriceEditText" 
           android:inputType="number"
           android:text="@string/tagPrice"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_span="3" 
           android:layout_weight="1">
     </EditText>
     </TableRow>

     <!-- totalPriceOutputRow -->
     <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/totalPriceOutputRow">

     <EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:id="@+id/totalPriceEditText" 
     android:text="@string/totalPrice"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_span="3" 
     android:inputType="numberDecimal" android:layout_weight="1">
     </EditText>
  </TableRow>
  </TableLayout>
```

from strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <string name="app_name">Tax Price Calculator</string>
     <string name="tagPrice">Tag Price</string>
     <string name="totalPrice">Total Price</string>   
</resources>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.finalproject.taxcalculator"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
  <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    <activity android:name="MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>
  </manifest>
```

Comment: so is some exception being thrown?

Comment: There is nothing except for telling me it has to stop. I am going crazy..Could you tell me your email so I could send you the file???

Comment: NFW, but feel free to expand your question

Comment: You need to use logcat and show us the error being reported. Logcat is built into eclipse, intelliJ and android studio but probably not netbeats so you will need to do the command line version http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html

Comment: ok...still thanks...but don't know how to expand the question because personally I can't find anything wrong there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems there is a mistake in variable assignment inside `onCreate()`, which resulting in `NullPointerException` when `totalPriceEditText` is referred.

```
tagPriceEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tagPriceEditText);
tagPriceEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.totalPriceEditText); // <- wrong?
```

Should be changed to

```
tagPriceEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tagPriceEditText);
totalPriceEditText= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.totalPriceEditText);
```

---

Your `TaxCalculator` activity is not registered yet in your `AndroidManifest.xml`
Either 1) change the name of app's entry point (if you don't have `MainActivity`), OR 2) add a new `<activity>` entry.

Example to change app's entry point to `TaxCalculator` (replace the current `<activity>`)

```
<activity android:name="TaxCalculator"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

---

Bonus: If your layout is already final, the code can be be cleaned up to this. This is just a suggestion for your current layout. I still don't know if you need `TableLayout` for future use or not though.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >
    <!-- tagPriceInputRow -->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tagPriceEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text="@string/tagPrice" >
    </EditText>
    <!-- totalPriceOutputRow -->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/totalPriceEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:text="@string/totalPrice" >
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yes that was a mistake I missed...Fixed it, ran it, but still the same result...:(

Comment: Thank you for the bonus, I am thinking after I get this run, I would make a button so the program would show the output after the user clicks the button. Can a button be added when the layout is linear? Sorry I know the question is stupid but I am really a beginner...

Comment: I just tested your code after the fix and I didn't get any error. The last thing I'm guessing the error is, the `TaxCalculator` activity is not registered yet in the `AndroidManifest.xml`. Could you edit your post and add the content of your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: Adding a `Button` is possible in `LinearLayout`. The real matter is how you want the app to look like, but I guess it's already off-topic in this question.

Comment: AndroidManifest.xml has been added. Thank you so much for helping me!

Comment: Teach this man to fish and have him read the logcat for the error else we will be here forever speculating and he won't learn anything.

Comment: Edited, see the updated answer. @sgarman Agree, but still, if I can help him with his problem, wouldn't it be great? I just hope that he will learn from this though.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. It works. My instructor just gave me a program and did not explain anything about it so it was pretty hard to get everything...Just checked the program he provided and he changed the activity name... So it means I need to change the activity name for each program?

Comment: It's up to you to whether you want to change it or not. Note that if you do that, you will need to change the class name + filename, and change the activity name inside the manifest file.